# Mysql if statement if one colum isn't empty, compare two others

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm having some trouble with an If statement in mysql - I'm pretty new to this.

```
SELECT c.* FROM cca_coupons c
JOIN cca_owners o ON o.id = c.owner_id
WHERE o.id='1'
  AND IF c.max_redemptions != '0' THEN c.amount_generated >= c.max_redemptions
```

I can't seem to get this working - I want to `SELECT c.*` where `c.amount_generated >= c.max_redemptions` only if `c.max_redemption`s doesn't equal `'0'`.

I have other conditions I'd like to include in this query including:  `WHERE active='0' OR expiration_date > now()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cca_coupons c
JOIN cca_owners o ON o.id=c.owner_id
WHERE c.amount_generated >= c.max_redemptions
AND c.max_redemptions <> '0'
```

Is 'max_redemptions' a number or a string?

Comment: Hi. Its a number, but if its blank, then it signifies unlimited and I don't want those rows selected. However, I have other conditions where I'd like to select rows in the same query `WHERE active='0' OR expiration_date > now()`